# Problem dual booting windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot, upgrade

I had windows 8 for like 12 months
Yesterday I choose to install ubuntu 14.04. 
On windows 8 I had 2 partitions C(where windows was installed) and D(other ntfs partition).
I shrunk D with 50 GB then I proceed to install ubuntu from usb.
After I finished installing ubuntu(6 gb swap area....).
I realised that Ubuntu is my default operating system and I don't have that grub menu.I installed that too using boot repair now I got it but I don't have the windows entry.I need to add the windows entry||
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried: http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot

Comment: @Ohnana - this is on-topic here or there, so it's OK if it stays.